# jquery bg transition loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking to loop my backgrounds. It plays once, image 1 - 3 then stops once it transitions to the 3rd background image. I believe that the process continues in memory, however the bg does not repeat from the first image through the sequence (loop)

How can I reorganize this to function as intended it?

HTML

```
<div class="bg_spinner"></div>
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="current"><a href="images/bg_img1.jpg">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="images/bg_img2.jpg">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="images/bg_img3.jpg">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.spinner').fadeOut();
    $('body').css({overflow:'inherit'})
});
swfobject.registerObject("FlashID");

function nextbg(){ 
    $(".pagination .current").next().children("a").click();
}
setInterval(nextbg,14000);
```

..............................................................................

```
var fl;
```

$(document).ready(function() {

```
var w_img=2800, h_img=1700;
var w,new_w,h, new_h, num;
var h_cont=1000, h_cont_new=1000;
setWidth();
setHeight();
w=new_w;h=new_h;
setSize();
function setWidth(){
    new_w=$(window).width();
}
function setHeight(){
    new_h=$(window).height();
}
function setSize(){
    if ((w/w_img) > (h/h_img)) {
        w_img_new=w+20;
        h_img_new=~~((w+20)*h_img/w_img);
    } else {
        h_img_new=h+20; 
        w_img_new=~~((h+20)*w_img/h_img);
    }
    $('#bgSlider img').css({width:w_img_new, height:h_img_new});
    if (h>h_cont) {
        m_top=~~((h-h_cont)/2);
    } else m_top=0
    $('.box').stop().animate({paddingTop:m_top+20},1000, 'easeOutCirc');
    h_cont_new=h_cont
}
setInterval(setNew,1);
function setNew(){
    setWidth();
    setHeight();
    if (fl) {h_cont=800;} else {h_cont=1000;}
    if ((w!=new_w)||(h!=new_h)||(h_cont_new!=h_cont)) {
        w=new_w;h=new_h;
        setSize();
    }
}
```

})

Comment: Most such functions require that you keep track of which element you're on and return to the first one when you get to the last. I don't see that here.

Comment: I don't see any element with the class "spinner" for one... So maybe change bg_spinner to spinner?

Comment: Can you show the code for the click handler? I assume you add the current class in there. If so you just need to add the current to the first-child if next() does not exist

Comment: Appreciate the update to the question, but I don't see any click handlers for $(".pagination .current").next().children("a").click();

Answer (score 1):

Most such functions require that you keep track of which element you're on and return to the first one when you get to the last. I don't see that here. It would look something like this:

```
var count;

function nextbg(){    
    if (count < $(".pagination li").length)
       $(".pagination li.current").next().children("a").click();
       count++;
    } else {
        $(".pagination li").first().children("a").click();
        count = 0;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't your .current length return 1 at all times?

Comment: Yeah. I was in a hurry. Updated.

Comment: Wouldn't $(".pagination .current").length still return 1 at all times. I am assuming OP removes the .current from the current element and add it to the next in his click handler. But I guess it's hard to say without seeing OP's click handler

Comment: Good call. Updated again. (I probably shouldn't be working on SO while working on other things. :-) )

Comment: Well $(".pagination li").next() wouldn't work too well. I think that part you had it right with the current. Or use .eq() with count to determine the current. Either way it is hard to say without seeing the click handler.

Comment: Good grief. You're right again. I'd have to use get() with the index or something.